# Rails: ActiveRecord Queries with Interdependent Subset Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It's possible to make an ActiveRecord query with a subset of conditions. For instance:

```
Client.where(:orders_count => [1,3,5])
```

Presumably, you could do this with multiple subsets:

```
Client.where(:orders_count => [1,3,5], :location => ["Austin", "New York", "Chicago"])
```

What if you wanted those two subsets to be interdependent, as with an polymorphic relationship:

```
Client.where(:clientable_type => ["business", "charity", "business"], :clientable_id => [1, 1, 2])
```

So this query would effectively look for `Client.find_by(:clientable_type => "business", :clientable_id => 1)`, `Client.find_by(:clientable_type => "charity", :clientable_id => 1)`, and `Client.find_by(:clientable_type => "business", :clientable_id => 2)`. But not, `Client.find_by(:clientable_type => "charity", :clientable_id => 2)`, as it would link the first item from each array, then the second item from each array, then third, etc.

Is it possible to write a query like that?

Answer (score 0):

I may not be 100% correct but I believe can chain two `where` clauses together. Example of this would be.

```
@person = Person.where(name: "David").where(age: 22)
```

When this activerecord query is executed it also issues another query

So when the above acitverecord query is executed it would be doing the following

```
SELECT name, age
FROM person
WHERE name = "David", 
AND age = "22";
```

So with that being said I believe the following query you want is as followed:

```
@client = Client.where(:orders_count => [1,3,5].where
                                  (:location => ["Austin", "New York", "Chicago"]
```

What I believe the above should do is check all clients where the `orders_cont` is 1,3,5 in the locations Austin, New York and Chicago and give you your response.

**Update**

[API Ruby on Rails - Where](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) provides the following example:

```
User.where(["name = :name and email = :email", { name: "Joe", email: "joe@example.com" }])
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Joe' AND email = 'joe@example.com';
```

With that being said I alternatively come up with the following:

```
Client.where(["orders_count = :orders_count and location = :location", 
       {orders_count  "1", "3", "5" location: "Austin", "New York", "Chicago"}])
```

So SQL output I believe would also be along the following lines.

```
SELECT orders_count, location
FROM orders_count, location 
WHERE orders_count = "1, 3, 5", 
AND location = "Austin, New York, Chicago;
```

Comment: Thanks! This does what you says it does, though it's a little different from what I was asking (very unclearly) for. Rather than getting all the resources with any combination of 1, 3, 5 and Austin, New York, Chicago--I was hoping to only get resources that meet combine these conditions in the given order. For instance, {1, Austin} and {3, Chicago} work, but not {1, Chicago}. Sorry that my question was unclear. I somehow doubt this is possible with ActiveRecord.

Comment: @timothythehuman If i understand correctly you want to match elements to your array?

Comment: I'm not sure what you, actually, but maybe if I'm more specific, you can be confident about what I mean. In my app, I have an array of condition hashes that looks like this: [{followable_id: 1, followable_type: "User"}, {followable_id: 5, followable_type: "Organization"}]. These are obviously based off a polymorphic relationship, though I'm not querying for the polymorphic object (such as "User" or "Organization") but rather for the actual polymorphic table "Follow". I'm trying to find all the "Follow" instances that meet one of the set of hash conditions in the array.